# How to block an email permanently on Outlook.com?

Tags: outlook.com, spam-prevention

Why do I keep getting emails from whatever@1und1.de? I added them to my blocked senders list as seen here:
[image]

But I keep receiving emails from that same sender:
[image]

I'm really confused as to why this doesn't work, and how to **actually** block senders.